# Python Web crawler, crawl through links and find specific words

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

So I am trying to code a web crawler that goes into a each chapter of a title for a Statue and count occurrence of a set a key words ("shall" "must") in its content.

Below is the code i used to acquire links to each chapters.
The base URL I used is http://law.justia.com/codes/georgia/2015/

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
import re
from collections import Counter

pattern1 = re.compile(r"\bshall\b",re.IGNORECASE)
pattern2 = re.compile(r"\bmust\b",re.IGNORECASE)


########################################Sections##########################
def levelthree(item2_url):
 r = requests.get(item2_url)
 for sectionlinks in     BeautifulSoup((r.content),"html.parser",parse_only=SoupStrainer('a')):
  if sectionlinks.has_attr('href'):
   if 'section' in sectionlinks['href']:
         href = "http://law.justia.com" + sectionlinks.get('href')
         href = "\n" + str(href)
         print (href)



########################################Chapters##########################
def leveltwo(item_url):
    r = requests.get(item_url)
    for sublinks in BeautifulSoup((r.content), "html.parser", parse_only=SoupStrainer('a')):
        if sublinks.has_attr('href'):
            if 'chapt' in sublinks['href']:
                chapterlinks = "http://law.justia.com" + sublinks.get('href')
                # chapterlinks = "\n" + str(chapterlinks)
                #print (chapterlinks)


######################################Titles###############################
def levelone(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    for links in BeautifulSoup((r.content), "html.parser", parse_only=SoupStrainer('a')):
        if links.has_attr('href'):
            if 'title-43' in links['href']:
                titlelinks = "http://law.justia.com" + links.get('href')
                # titlelinks = "\n" + str(titlelinks)
                leveltwo(titlelinks)
                # print (titlelinks)


###########################################################################
base_url = "http://law.justia.com/codes/georgia/2015/"
levelone(base_url)
```

The problem is that the structure of the page are usually **title - chapter - sections - contents** ( ex: http://law.justia.com/codes/georgia/2015/title-43/chapter-1/section-43-1-1/)

But there are ones that are **title - chapter - articles - sections - contents** (ex.http://law.justia.com/codes/georgia/2015/title-43/chapter-4/article-1/section-43-4-1/ )

I am able to get the links for the first scenario. However, I will miss all the title- chapter - article - sections - contents

My questions is, how can I code this so that I will be able get contents for each chapter (from sections links and from article to sections links) then look for the occurrence of words (such as "shall" or "must") for each chapter individually?

I want to find the word frequency by chapters, hopefully the output will be something like this

chapter 1

```
Word     Frequency
shall     35
must      3
```

chapter 2

```
Word     Frequency
shall     59
must      14
```

Comment: you do what you did on titles to chapters but for chapters to sections and sections to contents. You answered yourself at the end!

Comment: For this kind of thing, I advise you to use [scrapy](http://www.scrapy.org). It's a powerful webcrawler that you can setup rules for and will do exactly what you want

Comment: @RafaelAlmeida    yes, I am aware I can do the same for sections, the problem is that, some of them are articles link leads to section links, I want to know how to set up a condition so i can get contents in both scenario

Comment: It depends on what you want the final output to look like in both cases. Do you want nested lists? A big string? I think classes would be best. Also, are you asking how to structure your code, or how to detect whether the page is a section or an article linking to sections? For the latter we'd need to see a page with section links and an example of something you tried that failed.

Comment: @AlexHall I edited my post, see if it helps you

Comment: Complete your code to actually count words in the first scenario. It will be easier to modify it to allow the second scenario if you're actually returning data instead of just printing links.

Comment: @AlexHall I guess I wasn't being clear, that was part of the question, how to get contents from obtained links. My logic was to obtain links from both scenario first and then get contents from it.

Comment: I don't think a file will add anything towards accomplishing your goal. Your question seems to have three parts now, which is not how questions here should be. The first is how to handle the different types of pages. The second is how to extract text from a page. The third is how to count words in a string. Try tackling the middle one in isolation, and if you get stuck, post a question about only that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112327/discussion-between-alex-hall-and-tian-ma).

Comment: @AlexHall, so back to your original request, I am able to do the everything mentioned above for first scenario, now how to do it for second scenario? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37313733/python-web-scraping-counting-the-occurrence-of-a-list-of-words-of-each-page/37314473#37314473)

Comment: As I said before, it'll be easier to show once you return data instead of just printing it. I'll keep an eye on the chatroom.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112359/discussion-between-tian-ma-and-alex-hall).

Answer (score 0):

## for this problem, count '/' in urls

http://law.justia.com/codes/georgia/2015/title-43/chapter-1/section-43-1-1/)
http://law.justia.com/codes/georgia/2015/title-43/chapter-4/article-1/section-43-4-1/ )

```
if url.count('/') == 9:
    # do somthing
if url.count('/') == 10:
    # do somthing
```

## or you can do a simple trick:

```
part = url.split('/')
title = part[7]
chapter = part[8]
section = part[-1]
```

Note: -1 means last part

## to count shall or must:

use count function for the same

```
shall_count = response_text.count('shall')
must_count = response_text.count('must')
```