# Python web scraping, counting the occurrence of a list of words of each page

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, frequency

So i am trying to find a set of specific word ("shall" "may" "must" etc) of each page, and add up its occurrence, the code I used:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
import re


def levelfour(main_url):

    pattern = re.compile(r"\bmay not\b", re.IGNORECASE)
    pattern1 = re.compile(r"\bshall\b", re.IGNORECASE)
    pattern2 = re.compile(r"\bmust\b", re.IGNORECASE)
    pattern3 = re.compile(r"\bprohibited\b", re.IGNORECASE)
    pattern4 = re.compile(r"\brequired\b", re.IGNORECASE)

    r = requests.get(main_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup((r.content), "html.parser")
    results = soup.find('article', {'id': 'maincontent'})
    results = results.text.encode("utf-8", "ignore")

    total = 0
    total1 = 0
    total2 = 0
    total3 = 0
    total4 = 0

    m = re.findall(pattern, r.content)
    m1 = re.findall(pattern1, r.content)
    m2 = re.findall(pattern2, r.content)
    m3 = re.findall(pattern3, r.content)
    m4 = re.findall(pattern4, r.content)
    total += len(m)
    total1 += len(m1)
    total2 += len(m2)
    total3 += len(m3)
    total4 += len(m4)
    print total, total1, total2, total3, total4

########################################Sections##########################
def levelthree(item2_url):
 r = requests.get(item2_url)
 for sectionlinks in BeautifulSoup((r.content),"html.parser",parse_only=SoupStrainer('a')):
  if sectionlinks.has_attr('href'):
   if 'section' in sectionlinks['href']:
         href = "http://law.justia.com" + sectionlinks.get('href')
         levelfour(href)

########################################Chapters##########################
def leveltwo(item_url):
 r = requests.get(item_url)
 for sublinks in BeautifulSoup((r.content),"html.parser",parse_only=SoupStrainer('a')):
  if sublinks.has_attr('href'):
   if 'chapt' in sublinks['href']:
         chapterlinks = "http://law.justia.com" + sublinks.get('href')
         levelthree(chapterlinks)
         print (chapterlinks)

######################################Titles###############################
def levelone(url):
 r = requests.get(url)
 for links in BeautifulSoup((r.content),"html.parser",parse_only=SoupStrainer('a')):
    if links.has_attr('href'):
        if 'title-54' in links['href']:
          titlelinks = "http://law.justia.com" + links.get('href')
          # titlelinks = "\n" + str(titlelinks)
          leveltwo(titlelinks)
          # print (titlelinks)

###########################################################################
base_url = "http://law.justia.com/codes/idaho/2015/"
levelone(base_url)
```

when I print out total, total1, total2, total3, total4, it gives a zeros instead [0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ] my question, how do can appropriately find and add up the occurrence of this set or words?

Comment: did you try printint `repr(line)` in your loop ... and checking one of your m's afterword?  printing an intermediate value is often a quick way to get to the bottom of your problem ... if that doesnt solve it put a break point and run it in debug mode(pycharm has a very good and easy to use debug mode)

Comment: @JoranBeasley   so when I run repr(line) in my loop, i got '\t' for each line, when i try str(line) I got blank space instead. and m's are  [ ], it seems that the `re.findall` is not picking up strings from my `results`

Comment: then try looking at r.content

Comment: @JoranBeasley if i get your question right, I checked my `results` and I was able to print out the contents of the page.

Comment: keep going you can narrow it down to what the problem is and how to fix it by printing things.... are you sure there is an instance of `<article id="maincontent">`  (try and print `repr(results)`)

Comment: @JoranBeasley, ok, so instead of doing `m = re.findall(pattern, line)`, I used `m = re.findall(pattern, r.content)`, and was able to get the output. but I am not entirely sure why, and yes, there is an instance of `<article id="maincontent">`

Answer (score 1):

use `m = re.findall(pattern, r.content)` fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

Using a variable for each phrase is a mess. Try this:

```
from collections import Counter
counter = Counter()
text = r.content.lower()
for phrase in ['may not', 'shall', 'must']:
    counter[phrase] += len(re.findall(r'\b%s\b' % phrase, text))
```

Comment: This is not the same as a regex, the regex uses word boundaries which catches exact matches, this counts partial matches.